# Perl Output issues

Tags: perl, printing

This is going to seem extremely trivial, but it just doesn't make any sense to me.

I have the following snippit of code:

```
foreach $i (@inputtext)
{
@line = split(/\|/, $i);
 foreach $j (@line)
 {
  print "$j, ";  
 }
}
```

The input is three of the following lines, identical:

> 98465895|No idea what goes here|123 anywhere lane|city|ST|55555|data1|pass1|data2|pass2|data3|pass3|more stuff

The output ends up being this though:

> 98465895, No idea what goes here, 123 anywhere lane, city, ST, 55555, data1, pass1, data2, pass2, data3, pass3, more stuff
>   , 98465895, No idea what goes here, 123 anywhere lane, city, ST, 55555, data1, pass1, data2, pass2, data3, pass3, more stuff
>   , 98465895, No idea what goes here, 123 anywhere lane, city, ST, 55555, data1, pass1, data2, pass2, data3, pass3, more stuff

There is no logical reason I can see that would create an endline inside a print statement, throwing the comma onto the next line, and messing up the next lines of the output.  Anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can't see what's reading from the file.  Are you calling `chomp` on your input text to get rid of the trailing newline?

Also, instead of doing that `for` loop to join the fields with commas, do this:

```
print join( ', ', @line );
```

Answer (score 2):

I bet `$i` contains a newline character before you `split` it.  Try `chomp`ing it first.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure whats before this code, but I'd bet it's something like this:

```
open FILE, 'filename';
@inputtext = <FILE>;
```

Perl is optimized for you to approach the problem differently:

```
use strict; use warnings;  # helps you avoid errors early

open my $file, '<', 'filename' or die $!;

while (<$file>) {                   # loads the next line from $file into $_
    chomp;                          # strip newline from $_
    print join ', ' => split /\|/;  # split uses $_ without an arg
    # or use split's output for anything else
}
```

if you are using this code in a subroutine, be sure to `local $_;` before the `while` loop.